# How to open Xcode editor in mac Terminal?

Tags: xcode, editor

Just like MacVim, I usually use something like `mvim myFile.java` to open a new file. How to open an **empty file** with Xcode editor in Terminal, something like `Xcode myFile.py`?

Edit: Note that I want to open an empty file which could be `.py`, `.c`, `.cc`, or so, with Xcode editor. Not a Xcode Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file already exists, use `open`:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/ /path/to/sourcefile.c
```

Comment: @Ufomammut Then you have to create it first: `touch path/to/file.py`